# How to process Scala case class objects from Kafka using streaming queries?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Kafka+Spark integration where I am sending case class object (Website) and map into spark.

```
    case class Website(id: Int, name: String)

    implicit val productSchema = Encoders.product[Website]
    val website = Website(1,"lokesh")
    EmbeddedKafka.publishToKafka(topic, website.toString)(config,new StringSerializer)

    val df:Dataset[Website] = spark
          .readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("subscribe", topic)
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:1244")
          .option("startingoffsets", "earliest")
          .load()
          .select("value") 
          .as[Website]
```

I get the error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: [value];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use proper serialization format, e.g. JSON or Avro.

---

The following code sends out a textual representation of the `Website` case class.

> EmbeddedKafka.publishToKafka(topic, website.toString)(config,new StringSerializer)

The following code takes the textual representation as `Array[Byte]`:

> .select("value")

So you'd be better off casting the value to a string and simply...parse to make out an object, e.g. `.select($"value" cast "string")`.

With that, you'd be better off sending out a JSON representation of the `website` object that would make parsing so much easier. You could also use a comma-separated "serialization format", but that would require that your `website`s do not have any fields with commas.

---

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: [value]

The above exception says that you want to make an object of type `Website` (that is made up of `id` and `name` fields) from `value` which is clearly not possible.

After `.select("value")` the only column is `value` (obvious) and so `.as[Website]` is not possible as there are no "parts" of `Website` type to fill out (by name).